# different overlay content based on json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an overlay structure that I want to get populated by the content of a json file via jquery ajax. The overlay is triggered by a class:

```
<div class="js-overlay-start" data-overlay="js-overlay--type1">
  open overlay
</div>
```

This triggers the overlay and opens the html structure for it which looks like this:

```
<div class="overlay" data-open-overlay="js-overlay--type1">
    <img class="json-front" src="">
    <img class="json-back" src="">
</div>
```

the js for it is:

```
$(".js-overlay-start").unbind("click").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body,html").css("overflow","hidden").css("position","fixed");
    var dataOverlay = $(this).attr("data-overlay");
    $("body").find("[data-open-overlay='" + dataOverlay + "']").show();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'json/overlay.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var item = data.items[0];

            $('.json-front').attr("src", "");
            $('.json-back').attr("src", "");
            $('.json-front').attr("src", item.front);
            $('.json-back').attr("src", item.back);
        } //success
    });//ajax



    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".overlay").addClass("o1");
    }, 100);
});
```

and the json file looks like this:

```
{
    "items": [{
        "title": "first",
        "front": "http://placehold.it/810x2028?text=front",
        "back": "http://placehold.it/810x2028?text=back"
    },
    {
        "title": "second",
        "front": "http://placehold.it/810x2028",
        "back": "http://placehold.it/810x2028"
    }]
}
```

basically I'm looking for a way to open the overlay and the `img src` to be populated based on the `title` in the json (or something else if it's more convenient) so it can choose the appropriate `src`s. I'm successful when the item is only one, but I have no idea how to manage this distinction.

any heads up or solution is greatly appreciated. thanks a lot :)

Comment: You have any element to select the title from ajax call like a dropdown or button ???

Comment: Is `data-open-overlay="js-overlay--type1"` equal to `"title": "first"`?

Answer (score 1):

It might be more efficient if you make the ajax request first and store the data ready for the click events (rather than making an ajax request for each click). I havn't done this as it wasn't what you were asking, but something to consider.

Below I've grabbed the unique identifier for your click (ie. type1 from `data-overlay`) then used this to select the right object from your json file.

```js
$(".js-overlay-start").unbind("click").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body,html").css("overflow","hidden").css("position","fixed");
    var dataOverlay = $(this).attr("data-overlay");
    $("body").find("[data-open-overlay='" + dataOverlay + "']").show();
    var itemId = $(this).attr("data-overlay").split('--')[1]; // This is where you can grab the unique identifier 



    $.ajax({
        url: 'json/overlay.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.json-front').attr("src", "");
            $('.json-back').attr("src", "");
            $('.json-front').attr("src", data['items'][itemId].front);
            $('.json-back').attr("src", data['items'][itemId].back);
        } //success
    });//ajax



    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".overlay").addClass("o1");
    }, 100);
});
```

And a few changes to your json file so it's easier to traverse

```js
{ items: {
     type1: {
        "title": "first",
        "front": "http://placehold.it/810x2028?text=front",
        "back": "http://placehold.it/810x2028?text=back"
        },
     type2: {
        "title": "second",
        "front": "http://placehold.it/810x2028",
        "back": "http://placehold.it/810x2028"
    }
 }
}
```